# How to find the common demoninator on this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have the following equation:

$\frac57\left[\frac28-\left(\frac{2x}{10}-\frac49\right)\right]=\frac{2}{12}\left(\frac5{11}-\frac35\right)$

The only way I find to get the common denominator on this equation is multiplying $7,8,10,9,12,11,5$ which results in a rather large number: $3,326,400$.

Is this the right way to get the common denominator on this equation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you want to find the least common denominator, you need to find the least common multiple of (in your case) $7$, $8$ , $10$, $9$, $12$, $11$, $5$.

So, this number - call it $L$ should be divisible by $5$ and $8$ (and hence by $10$, too). So the numbers left are $7$, $8$ , $5$, $9$, $12$, $11$.

$L$ is divisible by $8$ and $9$, hence by $12$, too. So the numbers left are $7$, $8$ , $5$, $9$, $11$. These numbers do not have common divisors (except for $1$), hence the least common multiple is indeed their product, which is $27720$, which is much simplier.

In general case, you can use the recurrence $$lcm(x_1,\dots,x_n) = lcm(x_1,(lcm(x_2,\dots,x_n))).$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac57\left[\frac28-\left(\frac{2x}{10}-\frac49\right)\right]=\frac{2}{12}\left(\frac5{11}-\frac35\right)\\\frac{125}{252}-\frac{x}{7}=-\frac{4}{165}\\\frac{125}{252}+\frac{4}{165}=\frac{x}{7}\\x=7\frac{165\cdot125+4\cdot252}{165\cdot252}=\frac{165\cdot125+4\cdot252}{165\cdot36}=\frac{55\cdot125+4\cdot84}{55\cdot36}=\frac13\left(\frac{125}{12}+\frac{28}{55}\right)$$